# Raster drop down menu

Tags: qgis, raster, dropdownlist

My QGIS Raster drop down menu use to have 8 items in the menu. Now it only has 3. Unsure where these remaining 5 items have gone.

If I search Merge, for an example, this function is no longer found?

[image: Raster with 8 items]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Please [Edit] your question to specify the exact software you are using, and more information about the procedure between the first image and the second.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins menu, select Installed tab and turn on the Processing plugin

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks a bunch user2856. Quick easy result and appreciated !!

Comment: @Steffarhn If that worked, please accept my answer - https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers